# Yoast SEO: remove og:description and twitter:description on certain page

Tags: wordpress, seo, yoast

how can i remove the og:description and twitter:description tag for a certain page with the yoast-seo plugin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it on my own:

```
add_filter("wpseo_opengraph_desc", "remove_yoast_og");
add_filter("wpseo_twitter_description", "remove_yoast_og");
function remove_yoast_og($description) {
    if (is_page(1093)) {
        return false;
    }

    return $description;
}
```

Comment: But this answer does not do any justice with the asked question. You had asked _how can i remove the open graph tags_ but this answer only remove `og:description` and `twitter:description` not the whole/all og tags. So I think either the question is wrong or the answer.